# Enabling/Disabling of Text Box on click of different Radio Buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 4 radio buttons in a group, say 1,2,3,4 and along with radiobutton1 there are two more  input text boxes.
When I  select **radiobutton1** then those text boxes are enabled but on selecting **radio button 2,3,4** -- text boxes are disabled.
After selecting **radio button 2,3,4** and having text boxes disabled, if I select back radiobutton1 then text boxes should be enabled againg.
And by default (on loading page first time), radio button 1 is selected along with text boxes enabled

This is my HTML code written in MVC3 using Razor view engine

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Search, "rb1", new { Checked = "true", id = "1" })radio 1 
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.textbox1, new { style = "width:11%" })
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.textbox2, new { style = "width:11%" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Search, "rb2", new { id = "2" })radio 2
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Search, "rb3", new { id = "3" })radio 3
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Search, "rb4", new { id = "4" })radio 4
```

I need to do this using jquery in minimum line of codes. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could show the markup after it's been parsed

Comment: Actually I am new to this site so no idea how you guys post HTML, JS code or else I had plan to upload screenprint of existing screen but I am unable to do so :(

Comment: Just view the page in your browser and look at the source, then paste it here

Comment: @user1053902 Please see this link for a guide on posting code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I have my View Page and JS uploaded here http://jsfiddle.net/pushkar_ravi/mLsC2/1/

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
     $("#r1").click(function () {
                $(".myText").attr("disabled", false);
            });

            $(".disableText").click(function () {
                $(".myText").attr("disabled", true);
            });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1"  />
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"  class="disableText" />
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r3"  class="disableText" />
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r4"  class="disableText" />
<input type="text" id="t1" class="myText" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="t2"  class="myText" disabled="disabled"  />
```

Comment: I have modified my question, if you can revisit and answer it .. it will be really great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).index() == 0) {
        $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="group" />
<input type="radio" name="group" />
<input type="radio" name="group" />
<input type="radio" name="group" />

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="radioContainer">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" />
    <input type="text" id="t1" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" id="t2"  disabled="disabled"  /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2" />
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" />
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4" />
<div>
```

js

```
// only one handler is attached to DOM
$("#radioContainer").click(function(e){
    var $t = $(e.target), $inputs = $(this).find('input');
    if( $t.is('input[name="radios"]') )
        $inputs.filter('[type="text"]').get(0).disabled = ($t.attr('id') == 'r1' ? false:true);
    });
```